# Are scriptures authentic or fictional?

Tags: scripture

Personally, I believe there is no fiction in our scriptures (I will neglect very minute ones)

Rather I've heard and read people calling the scriptures as fiction, using  questions like 'were Hindu gods married?', and with no actual references trying to prove the Puranas wrong and put forward the idea of fiction in the Puranas. Actually they try to put forward the complete fictional part of the scriptures.

I don't know if this question is out of scope or belief, yet is commonly asked one.

Coming to detail, what explanation I get, 'these scriptures are fictional, the Puranas are the set of stories to explain the way to do good but in an interesting manner.'

In short they are trying to call them just stories but not history, hence rendering them fictional.
E.g. The elephant head of Ganesha, and the story behind it.

Comment: the scriptures are neither authentic nor fictional. to say it is 'right' without conviction (I mean blindly accepting everything) is the same as telling it is 'wrong' without investigation (I mean dismissing the possibility). What is important is to have an open mind and perform thorough investigation into its possibilities. My personal belief is that all of Hinduism stories are based on the truth, though there may be some distortions over time, the basis is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Scriptures are authentic**, there is no doubt in it. But it is also true that some stories in them can be fictional.  Scriptures like the primary *puranas* and other texts were written not by ordinary humans, but by sages and saints who were able to know the past present and future. And it was neither the nature, nor the duty of the sages to lie, bewilder and mislead the humans. So whatever stories are there which seems fictional, are either have esoteric meanings that we don't understand or they are there for the greater good of explaining certain concepts and give knowledge in a story form. It is a commonly known fact that stories are an effective method of imparting knowledge. So the Yoga Vashishtha says about this in a similar context:

> O Rama, without an illustration, truth that has not be personally experienced, cannot be grasped just like without the light objects in the house cannot be seen in the night. [YV - 2.18.51]

Secondly, they are fictional in the sense that the sages were poets by nature and whenever necessary they used their poetic imagination to describe events and incidents more vividly and beautifully with ornamental language. But to tell and believe that the incidents never happened at all would be foolishness because that would be accusing the sages as liars. Only when one meets a sage that one can know how powerful they are, otherwise he will only be speculating just like a nice guy who once told me how could Vedavyasa know and write so many things in details if those were not his own imaginations? So all these are myths, that's why they are called mythology. But if they were all myths, how could Vedavyasa write the actual position of stars in the sky, planetary positions, etc. which have already been verified by researchers?

So thinking them fictional, undermining and neglecting them is only our lack of understanding. However, if we get the message or the esoteric meaning of the stories, then there is no problem in considering the stories as fiction. But if one loses faith thinking them to be fictions only, then he will cause his own degradation owning to the lack of faith in the sage's words. So the Gita says:

> *ajnas casraddadhanas ca samsayatma vinasyati
>
>   nayam loko 'sti na paro na sukham samsayatmanah* [BG - 4.40]
>
> **Meaning**
>   But ignorant and faithless persons who doubt the revealed scriptures do not attain God consciousness. For the doubting soul there is happiness neither in this world nor in the next.

Comment: I profoundly disagree with this answer.  I think the events in Hindu scriptures literally happened the way they're described, without any embellishment or allegory.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, but it seems there are some, phrases which we might not be able to understand, have contradictions to one linear pathway, like the story of how Brahma lost his fifth head ?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I profoundly agree with your disagreement. After all, neither you nor I, nor anyone else here was there (or remember) to verify whether they are fact or fiction. Now when those can't be verified, you are free to disagree. But hardly I have stated them to be fictions to cause such a PROFOUND disagreement!

Comment: @Mr.K I think for the most part any apparent contradictions we see are either due to our failure to grasp the literal meaning, or due to one or othe other of the two contradicting passage not being authentic, for instance, being a later interpolation to some scripture.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, yes you are right, but that what jabar wants to clarify, but you disagreed, I just wanted to know your actual feelings.

Comment: "But hardly I have stated them to be fictions to cause such a PROFOUND disagreement!"  Well, you're not saying that the stories fictions out of whole cloth, but you're still suggesting that some details are fictional or allegorical, and that's what I profoundly disagree with.  But yeah, we weren't there, at least in our current births :)

Comment: @Mr.K yes, in fact like Brahma, there can be many such questions regarding the events mentioned in the scriptures and there are many contradictions and variations present even of the same stories in different scriptures.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "any apparent contradictions we see are either due to our failure to grasp the literal meaning" - now I wonder whether you had read the answer or jumped direct into arguing because you find it fun! If you say scriptures have later interpolations and you don't have the original texts, then how can you say them to be authentic? You'll only say those parts as authentic which support your own beliefs and tell the opposites as later interpolations.

Comment: "now I wonder whether you had read the answer or jumped direct into arguing because you find it fun!"  Well, I do find arguing fun (it keeps the mind engaged in these holy subjects), but I did read your answer; you suggested that they're might be some hidden metaphorical or moral meaning we might be missing.  That's not what I'm saying; I'm saying that we might be simply be misunderstanding the actual literal meaning.  For instance a lot of confusion in the past about Rama's ancestry stemmed from people misinterpreting the statement "X is the scion of Y's family" as "X is the son of Y."

Comment: "If you say scriptures have later interpolations and you don't have the original texts, then how can you say them to be authentic?" You use textual analysis. For instance, you find out what parts if scripture use modern grammatical construction, which parts of scripture have characters speaking in uncharacteristic styles, you look at which manuscripts and oral tradition processes are most rigorous in preserving the text (that's how you know the Rig Veda has almost no interpolations excluding the Khila Suktas), etc. And sometimes it's obvious like a passage where Rama complains about Buddhists!

Comment: "You'll only say those parts as authentic which support your own beliefs and tell the opposites as later interpolations."  Well, I believe in taking the opposite route: you first determine what parts of scripture are authentic and what's a later interpolation to the text using fairly objective methods, and then you form your beliefs based on the parts of scripture you have good reason to believe is genuine.  By the way, Yoga Vasista is an example of a scripture considered to be interpolated, because the original manuscripts are about something different:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moksopaya

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Glad to know that you know how to detect later interpolations. And from your comments it seems you have formed your belief by such analysis of scriptures. So henceforth, when you say something is a later interpolation, I'll politely ask to provide the textual analysis for the same to prove it so. However, I was not asking that, I was asking, if you say or know a text has later interpolations, then can you say that the text is authentic? That is, how can you say that something is pure and without blemish when you know it has mixtures of impurity!

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan And it's quite fine to find fun in arguing on these subjects. Personal taste and preference of people vary, that's obvious. I know you find it fun to argue as you had already told me that before. But I find it fun to do *kirtan* or meditate in silent or play video games, so sorry I can't be a good opponent for you or any one else. Because arguments have no end, I can't always keep replying. So I have now written an argument policy on my profile for whoever would like to argue regarding his own opinions.

Comment: "I was asking, if you say or know a text has later interpolations, then can you say that the text is authentic? That is, how can you say that something is pure and without blemish when you know it has mixtures of impurity!"  You can filter out the impurities as best you can using textual analysis and other methods, and then once you've identified the authentic parts you can accept the authority of that.  I never said that I accept the authority of everything that's there in current manuscripts of Hindu scriptures.

Comment: @jabahar I like meditation and video games too!  Yes, it's absolutely fine if you don't always respond to my comments.    I just like making the comments, to keep the mind engaged and for the benefit of others. I don't mind if people don't reply back.  Anyway, it was nice talking to you.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan Rama complaining about Buddhist doesn't necessarily make it interpolation. If you see Buddhist cosmology there are 1000 Buddhas in a Kalpa. Before Gautam Buddha there were Kassapa Konagamana and Kakusandha Buddha respectively in this Kalpa. Hence it could be possible..

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan Later interpolations also doesnt necessarily makes a text inauthentic. Truths aren't just supposed to be revealed by Veda Vyas. Other sages in this Kali Yuga can also reveal the scriptures by being third person omnipresent to the events through meditation. Similar may be the case of Yoga Vasistha...But Arbitary Interpolations just made to show the supremacy of sect makes the text inauthentic..

Answer (score 3):

Yes K Cloud you are right. While I agree that everything may not be understandable or explainable in our scriptures but they contain a vast amount of wealth of knowledge. But what some people do today on purpose is they neglect that 99% part of knowledge and focus on that which is not explainable as of now. It is actually nothing but a great conspiracy behind it. To call everything from ancient India as myths, uncivilized, fiction etc so that Indians never feel proud of their ancient heritage and always feel ashamed of being Indian.